# Format the "empty list" text for ListView android

Tags: android, listview

How can I format the text displayed when the list is empty in an Android `ListView`?

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test_list"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"
     />
```

I want to set the typeface to a typeface from asset..

```
mTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttf");
mEmptyTextView = (TextView)findViewById(**????**)    
mEmptyTextView.setTypeface(mTypeFace);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to use `android.R.id.empty` for initializing `mEmptyTextView`. try it as :

```
mTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttf");
mEmptyTextView = (TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
mEmptyTextView.setTypeface(mTypeFace);
```

Comment: Will it work for ListFragment? In list_content.xml for API 22 for ListFragment there's @+android:id/internalEmpty is used.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/test_list"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="25sp"/>
```

Then you can find this view by id (dont use `android:` prefix):

```
import <your.package>.R;
...
mEmptyTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.empty);
```

Also ListView has a special method to set empty view:

```
ListView#setEmptyView
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setEmptyView(android.view.View)

BTW you need somehow hide empty TextView (without calling `#setVisible(View.GONE)` on `TextView`) by placing it into some sort of container and hide a container - but this is a bad way.

So either inflate `TextView` from different layout or create him at runtime.